# Inserir valores em um INPUT type="number" ou SELECT do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, select, input, cep

Tem como importar valores do banco de dados para um campo input ou select usando o html, php, Mysql e/ou bootstrap somente? (obs.:não domino Javascript nem Json)

Segue imagem para ilustrar, em seguida explico o que gostaria de fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No campo CEP, gostaria que pegasse valores já cadastrados no banco de dados e atualizasse a UF e a Cidade conforme fosse escolhido, e que no carregamento inicial da página ficasse em branco.

Caso não possua cadastro a ideia seria usar o " + " para permitir adicionar um novo, mas não gostaria de sair da página para não perder os dados já inseridos.

Pensei em usar um modal para pesquisar e incluir CEP's, mas não sei como deixar o input "desativado" e depois enviar valores...

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que poderia estar fazendo para solucionar isso?

Desde já agradeço!!!

Comment: Pode mostrar algum código, iria ajudar bastante, obrigado :)

Comment: Como você faz essa consulta no banco? Usa alguma arquitetura de projeto?

Comment: Agradeço o interesse de vocês em solucionar, mas segui a dica do jona1has e resolvi usando a API, assim não preciso criar o banco, apenas importar o dados e se houver preenche diretamente, o que é muito mais eficiente pelo fato de poder havar mais de um CEP por cidade e tal....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você vai ter que usar alguma api pra isso, estou usando uma no meu sistema que usa o viacep. vou te mandar um código como exemplo e você faz as alterações necessárias.

É só pra você ter uma ideia de como funciona.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$("#cep").blur(function() {

  //Nova vari�vel "cep" somente com d�gitos.
  var cep = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

  //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
  if (cep != "") {

      //Express�o regular para validar o CEP.
      var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

      //Valida o formato do CEP.
      if(validacep.test(cep)) {

          //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
          $('#street_address').val("...");
          $('#district').val("...");
          $('#number').val("...");
          $('#complement').val("...");

          //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
          $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {
            console.log(dados);
              if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                  //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                  $("#street_address").val(dados.logradouro);
                  $("#district").val(dados.bairro);
                  $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
                  $("#locality").val(dados.localidade);
                  $("#number").val('');
                  $("#complement").val(dados.complemento);
              } //end if.
              else {
                  //CEP pesquisado n�o foi encontrado.
                  clean_up_form_doc();
                  alert("CEP n�o encontrado.");
              }
          });
      } //end if.
      else {
          //cep � inv�lido.
          clean_up_form_doc();
          alert("Formato de CEP inv�lido.");
      }
  } //end if.
  else {
      //cep sem valor, limpa formul�rio.
      clean_up_form_doc();
  }
```

});
  });

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou muito!